# Parse.com nested queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to solution for nested queries.
Actually, i want to get all reviews for each movie.
I have two tables:

Movie:

[image: Movie]

Review:

[image: Review]

It's possible to calculate rating for each movie and set it to avgRating?
I don't know why, but i can't get all reviews for one movie.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setAvg", function(request, response) {

    var Movie = Parse.Object.extend("Movie");
    var MovieReview = Parse.Object.extend("MovieReview");

    var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);
    query.each(function(movie){
        var reviewQuery = new Parse.Query(MovieReview);
        reviewQuery.equalTo("relatedMovie", movie);
        reviewQuery.find({
          success: function(reviews){
               console.log(reviews);
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
    response.success("Migration completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
});
});
```

I getting in logs:

```
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.777Z][]
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.778Z][{}]
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.779Z][{},{}]
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.780Z][{},{}]
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.781Z][{},{},{}]
I2015-12-21T17:34:57.782Z][{},{}]
```

Comment: Don't forget `return` before `reviewQuery.find()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group By / Sum Aggregate Query with Parse Cloud Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095204/group-by-sum-aggregate-query-with-parse-cloud-code)

Comment: In addition to the options outlined in that question, there's also the option of using Cloud Code to update a separate table when ratings are inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: I already saw this answer. But for first, i need to get all reviews for each movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as possible.
Thank all for answers.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("setMovieRating", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var Movie = Parse.Object.extend("Movie");
var MovieReview = Parse.Object.extend("MovieReview");
var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);
query.each(function(movie){
        var reviewQuery = new Parse.Query(MovieReview);
        reviewQuery.equalTo("relatedMovie", movie);
        return reviewQuery.find().then(function(reviews){
            var avgRating = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<reviews.length;i++){
                avgRating+=reviews[i].get('starRating');
            }
            avgRating = avgRating/reviews.length;
            var floatRating = Math.floor(avgRating * 100) / 100;
            movie.set('avgRating', parseFloat(floatRating.toFixed(1)));
            console.log(movie);
            movie.save();
        });
}).then(function() {
    response.success("Success");
  }, function(error) {
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setAvg", function(request, response) {

    var Movie = Parse.Object.extend("Movie");
    var MovieReview = Parse.Object.extend("MovieReview");
    var reviewQuery = new Parse.Query(MovieReview);
    var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);
    query.equalTo("relatedMovie",reviewQuery);
    query.find(function(movie){
        //do whatever you want with the query results
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank for you answer, but it doesn't work.
Each review have relation to Movie.

Comment: do you want to get all the movies and then calculate the avg ?

Comment: I have table with movie_reviews.
Movie may contains 3 reviews. 
I need to calculate avg for each movie from 3 review.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several potential issues :

- You should use a background job instead of a function to ensure you have enough time
- You should define the reviewQuery inside the each block to avoid mixing
- If you can have more than 100 ratings for one movie, you should set the limit of query to 1000 (which is the maximum limit - if there could be more than 1000, you will have to make the same query several times while incrementing the skip parameter).

Comment: Thanx for your answer.
1) I use function only for tests.
2) I already fix it
3) Maximum - it's 3 ratings

Comment: When some reviews are missing, are there other reviews for the same movie which are not missing ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't fully understand, what you mean. 
Each movie contains 3 reviews. Data filled by script. Script check all data, before inserting.
Each review contains rating and related field to movie.